# fragment.getview() returning null from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager that hosts several fragments. One of them, Frag1, is supposed to recieve an object with data and poplulate some EditText with that data.

The thing is, when I try to access the fragment from the activity, getView() always returns null, making it impossible to call methods of the Frag1 class. I am using LogCat to check if other variables are null, but it seems that the problem is coming from the getView() check.

Any idea why it is null?

Activity code

```
   (...)

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form1);

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    return new Frag1();

                case 1:
                    return new Frag2();

                case 2:
                    return new Frag1();

                case 3:
                    return new Frag1();

                default:
                    return new Frag1();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }


    public void Populate(Patient patient) {
        Frag1 fragment = 
                  (Frag1) mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);

        Log.d(patient.getName(), "data check");
        Log.d(fragment.hello(), "fragment check");

        if (fragment.getView() == null) {
            Log.d("*** DEBUG ***", "found the problem champ");
        }

              if(fragment != null)  // could be null if not instantiated yet
              {
                 if(fragment.getView() != null) 
                 {
                    // no need to call if fragment's onDestroyView() 
                    //has since been called.
                    fragment.setName(patient.getName());
                    Log.d(patient.getName(), "supbrah");// do what updates are required
                 }
              }
    }
```

Fragment code

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {

EditText name;
Spinner spinner;
AutoCompleteTextView textView;
AutoCompleteTextView textView1;
Spinner spinner1;
AutoCompleteTextView textView2;
View v;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_form, container, false);

    name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.name_edit);

    return v;
}

public String hello() {
    return "sup brah";
}

public String getName() {
    String patient = name.getText().toString();
    return patient;
}

public void setName(String text) {
    name.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you use `getView().findViewById(R.id.name_edit);` and put it in onViewCreated?
The way it is now shouldn't work imo.

Here's some samplecode:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_form, container, false);

}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

name = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.name_edit);

}
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Regardless of that change, in the activity code, getView() still returns null... I think that's what is keeping me from getting setText to work.

Comment: This segment you indicated I changed it in the Fragment class. But then I am trying to call a method from that same class from the activity (Populate function) and it doesn't work because getView returns null.

Comment: And any chance you can show your viewpager?
And shouldn't: Frag1 fragment = 
              (Frag1) mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
be more like:
 Fragment fragment =  mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
Hard to say without showing your viewpager and the getItem function. :/

Comment: Also, I am using Frag1 fragment = (Frag1) etc., because my that fragment refers to the class Frag1.

Comment: using getView() inside onViewCreated is not counterproductive? The View is in the params, as view

Answer (score 2):

Try calling viewPager.getChildAt(int x); instead of viewPagerAdapter.getItem(int x).getView();

Comment: I still get the problem. Nothing is showing in the EditText field. setText is still not working after I replace that. You mean replacing fragment.getView() != null by viewPager.getChildAt(int x), right?